# getJson ajax request

Tags: getjson

Please help,
I have been trying to get Json data but with no avail.
I have managed to get it working in dreamweaver but once uploaded to my domain it then does not work.
I have looked at many examples but cant get mine to work. I have seen examples that get picturs from flikr that work on my domain.
I need to get the json data from http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now/

This works in dreamwaever

```
$.getJSON('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now/',
function(json) {   
$('#images1').text(json.timestamp);  
});
```

and this

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: MyUrl,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){alert("Success");hello(data);},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert("Error : "+" ':' "+textStatus+" ':' "+errorThrown);},
});}
```

is this a cross domain issue? why does the Flikr ones work as this is cross domain too? please help.
Many Thanks.

Comment: You need to include your code - what have you tried, error messages, etc

Comment: Code and error messages can be seen here http://mjmchain.com/JsonTest.html

Comment: I've tried lots of changes to the code but can't get it to work when it's on my domain. Works when I'm in dreamweaver. It's valid Json tested at jsonlint and jsonvalitator. Both these are able to display and its cross domain for these. Tied lots of different codes and JsonP. I get no transport, jquery xxx_xxx was not called, assess is denied and lots more with every thing I try.

Answer (score 0):

cross domain should be done using JSONP, checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp),  and the JSONP section [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).